# UIVideoEditorController videoQuality setting not working

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, uiimagepickercontroller, uivideoeditorcontroller

I'm currently trying to use `UIVideoEditorViewController` to trim a video file previously selected from the Photos app by using `UIImagePickerController`. I verified that after choosing the file and *before* creating `UIVideoEditorViewController` the file has the original resolution. However, after trimming the video, the output is always in 360p resolution despite setting the `videoQuality` property to `high`. All the applicable settings seem to be ignored for this property and the video ends up being compressed unnecessarily.

I have found multiple people reporting similar issues but yet have to find a workaround for this.

```
let editor = UIVideoEditorController()
editor.delegate = self
editor.videoMaximumDuration = 0 // No limit for now

// TODO: This should really work, however while testing it seems like the imported videos are always scaled down
// to 320p which equivalents the default value of .low.
editor.videoQuality = .typeHigh
editor.videoPath = internalURL.path
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a workaround for this?